# How to change AJAX data post with one variable to multiple variables using php/javascript?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

The following code posts only `card_no` through AJX using `cardData` variable. What would be the easiest way to add another variable `trace_no` to `data` via AJAX.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks

```
<tbody>
<?php
    if(!empty($PBBdata)):
        $i=1;
        foreach($PBBdata as $row){
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->trans_date.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->trans_date.'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
?>
<input type="button" name="view" value="<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>" id="<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view_data">
<?php
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->card_type.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->approval_code.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row->gross_cur.'</td>';
            echo '<td align="right">'.number_format($row->gross_amt,2).'</td>';
            echo '<td align="center">'.$row->trace_no.'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $i++;
     }
     endif;
?>        
</tbody>

......

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.view_data').click(function(){
  var cardData = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Finance/get_matchBYpan",
         method: "POST",
         data: {cardData:cardData},
         success: function(data){
            $('#hms_result').html(data);
            $('#modal_tableHMS').modal('show');
         }
        });
 });
});
</script>
```

// adding the Finance/get_matchBYpan codes

```
       public function get_matchBYpan()
       {
        $this->load->model('model_finance');

          $cardData = $this->input->post('cardData');
          $last4pan = substr($cardData,12);

          if(isset($last4pan) and !empty($last4pan))
          {
                 $records = $this->model_finance->matched_by_panPBB($last4pan);

                 $i=1;
                 $sumtotal =  0;
                 $output = '';


                 $output .= '

                        <h4 class="text-center"> Credit Card Number: '.$cardData.'</h4><br> 
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                               <th>No</th>
                               <th>Booking ID</th>
                               <th>PAN No</th>
                               <th>Approval Code</th>
                               <th>Method</th>
                               <th>Source</th>
                               <th>OTA</th>
                               <th>Amount</th>
                               <th>Variance</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';
                 if(!empty($records)):
                 foreach($records as $row)
                 {       

                        $output .= '      
                        <tr>
                               <td>'.$i.'</td> 
                               <td>'.$row->booking_id.'</td>
                               <td>'.str_pad($row->pan, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->approval_code.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->method.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->source.'</td>
                               <td>'.$row->ota.'</td>
                               <td align="right">'.number_format($row->total,2).'</td>
                               <td></td>
                        </tr>';
                 $sumtotal = $sumtotal + $row->total;      
                 $i++;
                 }
                 $output .= '
                        <tr>
                               <td></td> 
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td></td>
                               <td colspan="2"><b>GRAND TOTAL</b></td>
                               <td align="right">'.number_format($sumtotal,2).'</td>
                               <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>';
                 endif;
                 echo $output;

          }
   }
```

For model_finance->matched_by_panPBB($last4pan) will later be change to 
model_finance->matched_by_panPBB($last4pan,$traceNo); // traceNo get from AJAX which i don't know how to give that to AJAX

Comment: @Emma owh.. so just add in {cardData:cardData, trace_no:trace_no} ? but where AJAX get that trace_no? i try to declare var traceNo = $(this).attr('id') but error..

Comment: @Emma #modal_tableHMS is just the modal display code.. and #hms_results is where the retrieve data will be placed.

Comment: @Emma if i put traceNo = $(this).attr('id') it will have same value with cardData

Comment: var_dump($cardData) print out the value of cardData..eg: (XXX1234)  so if i put value="<?php echo $row->card_no; echo $row->trace_no; ?>".. var_dump($cardData) value is now XXX1234999 which 999 is the trace no.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change:

```
value="<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>"
```

to

```
value="<?php echo $row->card_no.'-'.$row->trace_no; ?>"
```

then, change:

```
$cardData = $this->input->post('cardData');
```

to

```
$cardData = $this->input->post('cardData');
$card_no = substr($cardData, 0,11); // depending on how you want to display you can change it 
$trace_no = substr($cardData,16,18); // you can replace this function with strpos()
```

and add:

```
<h4 class="text-center"> Credit Card Number: '.$card_no.'</h4>
<h4 class="text-center"> Trace Number: '.$trace_no.'</h4>
```

Comment: It is still not working.. 
value="{card_no:'<?php echo $row->card_no; ?>',trace_no:'<?php echo $row->trace_no; ?>'}" 
this impact my query which my query is based on card_no stored in value..

Answer (score 0):

In your view

`<input type="button" name="view1" value="<?php echo $row->trace_no ; ?>" id="<?php echo $row->trace_no ; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm view_data">` // if you dont want this to display hide it.

get the value using name = view1.

```
var trace_no = document.getElementsByName("view1"); // pass this to AJAX data

$.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>Finance/get_matchBYpan",
         method: "POST",
         data: {cardData:cardData,
                trace_no:trace_no
       },
```

receive trace_no in controller and pass it to model.

====================================================
If you're struggling to display the data on first time then

on windows.onload pass static value to trace_no. it will then work fine for the 1st time and for 2nd time `$('.view_data').click(function(){` will get triggered so pass the value of both the data or more, whatever you wanted.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: in Finance/get_matchBYpan.. how should i call it? I use $traceNo = $this->input->post('trace_no'); still not getting the value

Comment: $this->input->post('trace_no');..... can you use your "name" attribute?...

as per your code above, you are only passing cardData, can you update your code if you've included trace_no in AJAX?